# Bluetooth File Transfer Issue

Tags: file, bluetooth, transfer

My android phone does not show file transfer accepting window. Due to this situation, I can not send any file to my phone from my pc.

By the way, I have not altered my phone's operating system and kernel such as custom rom, kernel etc.

```
**My PC's Specs:**
**OS   :** Windows 10 Enterprise
**CPU  :** Intel I5 2430M @ 2.4 Ghz
**GPU 1:** Intel HD Graphics 3000
**GPU 2:** Nvidia GeForce 520MX
**RAM  :** 4 GB
**HDD  :** 500 GB (SATA 2)

**My Phone's Specs:**
**Manufacturer:** Samsung
**Model       :** I8190 (S3 Mini)
**OS          :** Android 4.1.2 Jelly Bean (Turkish)
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not able to send files on your phone using bluetooth.

Then possibly the reason behind it is that you need to pair both the devices, either by using the computer or the phone.

In phnoe it could be accomplished by :

Open Menu -> Goto Setting -> Wireless and network settings -> Bluetooth Settings -> Scan For Device -> Long Touch The Device Address Below Scan For Device -> Choose Pair

After performing the above steps you would be able to send files to the device you paired using bluetooth

Comment: My devices are already paired. But in spite of the that my devices are paired, I can not send any file to my phone.

Comment: DrakeMcCain then you should check your bluetooth visibility option, if it is off then turn it on and then try connecting it again

Comment: Turning on visibility did not solve my problem. But if I install a file transfer app to my phone via Google Play (meanwhile I tried "Bluetooth File Transfer" app), I can send any file to my phone. Because, this app bypasses file transfer permission. Which means; file transfers do not ask me for my permission if I use this app.